# Firebird triggers do not fire from application but do work in DB tools

Tags: delphi, triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm rusty on Firebird syntax/behavior so this might be a dumb question.

What I've run into is that 2 of 3 Firebird (version 2.5.4) triggers do not fire from a Delphi 6 application when they should. When a record is added or removed from a DevEx grid hooked to a TIBOQuery- the record is removed in the database when I check-but the after insert and after delete triggers are not firing against the table. The trigger that does work is an After Insert or Update trigger- and against a different table, but basically does the same thing- if a value on this table is updated, update another table column's value.

When I try manually adding or deleting a record from the table in either SQL Manager Lite or EMS for Firebird- the after insert/after delete triggers fire okay and behave as desired. So they work in the database tools, but not the app.  I checked permissions on the triggers and the table and granted all just to see if that was it but still no luck.

What could I be missing that would cause the triggers to work fine outside the app but not within it?  I know the app is using the correct DB because I can see the records get added/removed but not the triggers fire (no errors- but expected update to other table does not occur).

Comment: Have you checked in the database? Perhaps your app's queries just don't refresh themselves automatically.

Comment: Which Firebird driver is your Delphi app using?  Also, do you have the Interbase server service running on the same machine as your Firebird db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most bizarre problems, this had an easy answer that was overlooked due to the thought process of how the application works. Not to mention weariness of learning/taking on a new project and crazy commute. Anyhow ;-).

It turns out that the trigger actually WAS working from the app, but an unrefreshed data aware control was changing the value back when a Save button was clicked.

It's a form with several tabs.  Table A (table that gets updated by the trigger) is presented in the first tab, with data aware controls for it's fields.  Table B (table that has two triggers on it that update a field in Table A) is presented in the second tab in a data aware grid.  When the row was added/removed in the grid, it was removed in the DB- but because Table A was never refreshed in the app- when a Save button was clicked the old value for Table A field was saved over the value from the trigger.

Hope this lesson learned helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure because my triggers work as expected.  Are you setup to use auto committing in your data aware connection objects?  Otherwise you may need to commit the change (insert/update or delete etc.) before you can see the results of the trigger.

Check the settings of the objects linked to your data aware components.  There are a few settings relating to commit-read commit-write auto committing etc.

I hope I'm hitting into the right area.

Comment: This is a great suggestion and I did check these where I could find them.  Turns out it was not this though. Will post the answer shortly.